# Передача аргументов в программу через консоль Linux

Tags: c++, linux, консоль

Всем доброго времени суток.
Назрела такая проблема: при передаче параметров в консоли Linux выдает ошибку "Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)". Вот код программы (нужно вывести на экран требуемое число Фиббоначи по индексу):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "Your value is ";
    for (int i = 0; argc; i++){
        int a = atoi(argv[i]);
        if (a <= 2) cout << "1"; 
        else{
            int x = 1;
            int y = 0;
            int ansver;
            for (int j = 1; j <= a; j++)
            {
                    ansver = x + y;
                    x = y;
                    y = ansver;
            }
            cout << ansver;
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И сколько раз выполнится цикл

```
for (int i = 0; argc; i++)
```

Если `argc` всегда больше нуля?...

И еще - `argv[0]` - это просто имя самой программы (как правило), но никогда - не аргумент командной строки.

Словом, вот:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "Your value is ";
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        int a = atoi(argv[i]);
        if (a <= 2) cout << "1  ";
        else
        {
            int x = 1;
            int y = 0;
            int answer;
            for (int j = 1; j <= a; j++)
            {
                ansver = x + y;
                x = y;
                y = answer;
            }
            cout << answer << "  ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: получилось, спасибо! а если мне потребуется соединить данную программку с еще одним .cpp файлом, в котором я задаю новые ключи с нужными мне функциями, как это сделать, не подскажите?

Comment: Не очень понял, что вы хотите спросить...

Comment: например: " ls -aR ", только вместо -aR я прописываю новый ключ (допустим -z) и задаю ему нужную мне функцию. если я пытаюсь объединить мою мини-программу и файл с прописанными новыми ключами, то пишет "множественное определение main". если попытаться объединить два данных файла(т.е. в мою программу тупо вставить нужный код и забыть о проблемме), то, по-моему, это будет неверно

Comment: Все равно не понял. Так что выскажусь чисто теоретически - оформите этот код для чисел Фибоначчи как отдельную функцию. `main` должна заниматься только разбором командной строки и вызовом соответствующих функций (и, само собой, в программе она должна быть одна).

Comment: я бы добавил, что разбор строки надо бы структурировать. Посмотрите на исходники линуховых  утилит, там есть хороший паттерн разбора. Написав один раз, дальше нужно только добавлять  указатели на функции обработки в массивчик

Answer (score 1):

Так а что это за цикл такой

```
for (int i = 0; argc; i++)
```

Это бесконечный цикл. Неудивительно, что в какой-то момент доступ к `argv[i]` вылетает, учитывая, что `argv[argc]` всегда равно null-указателю. Может имелось в виду

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
```

?